# How to concat string properties of an array in an array of arrays and create a new property in each array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array of arrays which looks like below:

```
UserList=[
[name:"user1", type:"admin", location:"NY", expired:"NO"],
[name:"user2", type:"poweruser", location:"CO", expired:"NO"],
[name:"user3", type:"admin", location:"SF", expired:"NO"],
]
```

I want to add the three properties name, type and location and create a new property in each individual array like the property "AllProps" in the below example:

Desired Output:

```
UserList=[
[name:"user1", type:"admin", location:"NY", expired:"NO",AllProps:"user1adminNY"],
[name:"user2", type:"poweruser", location:"CO", expired:"NO",AllProps:"user1poweruserCO"],
[name:"user3", type:"admin", location:"SF", expired:"NO", AllProps:"user1adminSF"],
]
```

Can I do this using Loadash? What is the best and fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements and wanting to just modify your existing array without return a new one, simply iterate the array and add the key/value pair:

```js
var UserList = [
 {name: "user1", type: "admin", location: "NY", expired: "NO"},
 {name: "user2", type: "poweruser", location: "CO", expired: "NO"},
 {name: "user3", type: "admin", location: "SF", expired: "NO"},
];

UserList.forEach(function(x){
 x["AllProps"] = x.name + x.type + x.location;
}); 

console.log(UserList);
```

The upvoted answer will work fine, but there is no need to return anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `{}` but it should be `[]` for array. Also you need to use `:` instead of `=` in objects

```js
var userList= [
{name: "user1", type: "admin", location: "NY", expired: "NO"},
{name: "user2", type: "poweruser", location: "CO", expired: "NO"},
{name: "user3", type: "admin", location: "SF", expired: "NO"}
];

var output = userList.map(user => {
   user.AllProps = user.name + user.type + user.location;
   return user;
});

// Short hand
var output = userList.map(user => ({ ...user, AllProps: user.name + user.type + user.location}));

console.log('output:', output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is that you need:

```
_.forEach(UserList, function(u){
  var allPropValues = "";
  _.forOwn(u, function(value, key) {
     if(key !== 'expired') {
        allPropValues += value;
     }
  });  
  u.AllProps = allPropValues;
});
```

```js
var UserList=[
{name:"user1", type:"admin", location:"NY", expired:"NO"},
{name:"user2", type:"poweruser", location:"CO", expired:"NO"},
{name:"user3", type:"admin", location:"SF", expired:"NO"},
];
console.log({before: UserList});

_.forEach(UserList, function(u){
  var allPropValues = "";
  _.forOwn(u, function(value, key) {
     if(key !== 'expired') {
        allPropValues += value;
     }
  });  
  u.AllProps = allPropValues;
});

console.log({after: UserList});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.9/lodash.js"></script>
```